# Can there be any safeguards against opening and editing in saving the file in HEX? Any symbol or code?

Tags: windows

Because there are different program files with different extensions: * .anm, * .des. I downloaded programs to open these types of files and it doesn't open. And in other files with the extensions: * .dll, * .log, * .tga, * .dds, * .s, * .c, * .exe opens. I've been looking for a solution for a year. I read that it can be with attributes, but you can't change them in the file code, but I don't know how to check. I read somewhere that I can change something in HEX. That some kind of code or symbol. I do not know. You know? I hope for a quick response...
(I can hardly speak English)
(Below is the original version of my language. Go to Google Translate)

Bo są rózne pliki programu o różnych rozszerzeniach: *.anm, *.des. Pobrałem programy do otwierania tych rodzajów plików i nie otwiera. A w innych plikach o rozszerzeniach: *.dll, *.log, *.tga, *.dds, *.s, *.c, *.exe otwiera. Już rok szukam rozwiązania. Czytałem, że to coś może być z atrybututami, ale nie da się ich zmienić, w kodzie pliku, ale nie wiem jak sprawdzić. Gdzieś czytałem, że mogę coś zmienić w HEX. Że niby jakiś kod, czy symbol. Nie wiem. Wiecie? Liczę na szybką odpowiedź...

Comment: Your english is good. :)

Comment: What hex editor are you using? Can you rename the file, edit, then rename back?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably talking about file signature. A sequence, usually at the start of  a file, that will identify the format. You can change that ... but the result will probably not be usable (heavily depending on applications and file type/structure).

There are file formats and reasons why a file might lack such an identifier. On Linux you can use the command [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) to get an idea what something might be.

Wikipedia links:

- [List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)
- [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Comment: And can you give me your email address then I will send you a file and see what I mean.

Comment: No. If you do have an example file upload it and include the link in your question. Though it would be better to include the file itself in your question. E.g you can open it using a HEX editor and include the start of the file has a HEX representation in your question.